# Pydantic BaseModel schema and instance serialization/deserialization not working

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, pydantic

I am attempting to serialize a Pydantic model schema and then deserialize it in another script. The serialization process is working as expected, and it has created two JSON files: `model.json` and `data.json`.

In `test_save.py`, I defined the `MainModel` schema and then serialized it along with an instance of `MainModel`. The resulting JSON files contain the schema and data, respectively.

*test_save.py*

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
import json

# Model definition
class MainModel(BaseModel):
    foo: str

# Serialize MainModel
with open('model.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(MainModel.schema(), f, indent=4)

# Create Instance of MainModel
maindata = MainModel(foo = 'bar')

# Serialize Model Instance
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(maindata.dict(), f, indent=4)
```

*model.json*

```json
{
    "title": "MainModel",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "foo": {
            "title": "Foo",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "foo"
    ]
}
```

*data.json*

```json
{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

---

In `test_load.py`, I'm attempting to deserialize the `model.json` and `data.json` files. The **`create_model`** function from **`pydantic`** is used to define the **`MainModel`** schema based on the schema in **`model.json`**

*test_load.py*

```py
import pydantic
import json

with open('model.json', 'r') as f:
    j = json.load(f)
    MainModel = pydantic.create_model('MainModel', **j)

    with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
        maindata = json.load(f)
        # modelinstance = MainModel.validate(maindata)
        modelinstance = MainModel.parse_obj(maindata)
        print(json.dumps(modelinstance.dict(), indent=4)) # This print the schema instead of data.
```

I'm attempting to deserialize a Pydantic model instance using the schema stored in `model.json` and data stored in `data.json`. However, when I run the script, instead of printing the data as expected, the script prints the schema from `model.json`.

**The expected output from `test_load.py` is:**

```json
{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

**But the actual output is:**

```json
{
    "title": "MainModel",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "foo": {
            "title": "Foo",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "foo"
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me identify the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can even create the model 'on the fly' and refer to it in your code:

```
from datamodel_code_generator import generate
from pathlib import Path

# saves model to file
generate(
    input_=Path("your_model_schema.json"),
    input_file_type="jsonschema",
    output=Path("your_model.py")
)
```

And for using it in your code:

```
import importlib

Model = getattr(importlib.import_module("your_model"), 'Model')

path = Path('data_file.json')
your_json_data = Model.parse_file(path)
```

Tested with Python 3.10.

Answer (score 1):

> The `create_model` function from `pydantic` is used to define the `MainModel` schema based on the schema in `model.json`

That is the error.

I am not sure what made you think that this function takes a (`dict`-parsed) JSON schema as keyword arguments, but that is not how it works. To quote from the documentation of the [`create_model`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation) function:

> Fields are defined by either a tuple of the form `(<type>, <default value>)` or just a default value.

---

What happened in your case is that the dictionary containing the model schema was unpacked as keyword arguments and thus it constructed a model with the fields named `title`, `type`, `properties`, and `required`.

The first two were just passed strings (`"MainModel"` and `"object"` respectively), which the model creation function interpreted as the default values, inferring the type of both those fields to be `str`. The `properties` argument ended up being a dictionary, again interpreted as the default value for a field of the type `dict` and the last one got a list, which was again set as the default value for the `required` field of type `list`.

You can verify this by printing `MainModel.schema_json(indent=4)` after your `create_model` call.

Lastly, since you therefore had default values for all four fields *and* the default config setting for extra attributes is `Extra.ignore`, parsing your `data.json` resulted in the `foo` key to just be ignored, whereas all other fields were assigned their default values. That is how you ended up with a model **instance** that looked exactly like the model schema.

---

If you want to generate Pydantic models from a JSON schema, there is no built-in functionality for this. But the [Pydantic docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/datamodel_code_generator/) link the [`datamodel-code-generator`](https://github.com/koxudaxi/datamodel-code-generator/) package, which can do that (and more). But since this is code generation, it will not work at runtime. You'll obviously need to call the code generator first before launching the program that attempts to use those models.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.
I will  test with the datamodel-code-generator